# No module named jinja2

Tags: apache, python-3.x, virtualenv, pip, ubuntu-12.04

Im trying to deploy a Python3.2 app in my Ubuntu 12.04 server. Everything was fine, until I tried to use Jinja2 as my template system.

Im using **virtualenv** to use Pyhon3.2 instead of Python2, and I've installed other required libraries such as pymongo or bottle without problem. But now, my app fails because it says

```
ImportError: No module named jinja2
```

I've installed jinja2 the same way as I installed pymongo or bottle (using pip in the virtualenv), and they work just fine. If I try to install it again:

```
./virtualenv/bin/pip-3.2 install jinja2
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jinja2 in /var/www/virtualenv/lib/python3.2/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

It says that it is installed. I've tried to uninstall and install again with no luck.
Im trying to run the application using mod_wsgi, and I know it's using the right virtualenv, because I don't get any errors due to Pymongo, Bottle, what are installed using the virtualenv pip.

Any ideas? :(

Comment: Are you sure you don't have other (system-wide) installations of PyMongo and Bottle and `mod_wsgi` is using those instead?

Comment: How can I be sure? If I try to execute Python2 compatible code, like print 'hello', it says "syntax error". So it's using Python3, and I've never installed pymongo or bottle in any other way.

Comment: This [page](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments) might help you make you sure `mod_wsgi` is using your `virtualenv`.

Comment: Yep, I ried that aswell. Didn't work though :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jijna is not compatible with Python 3.2. See [this](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/intro/)